# Change data type of column from STRING format to DATE format

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, sqldatatypes

I am reading a file from ADLS location, in that one column **Period_Ending_Date** is having data type as STRING.
The Period_Ending_Date is having many dates in random order, I need to apply filter to get the latest date.

I'm trying this code:

**select * from final_table
WHERE Period_Ending_Date = (SELECT MAX(Period_Ending_Date) FROM final_table)**

But the problem is I'm getting the day with maximum, not the latest date. I can understand this is happening because of STRING data type. Please guide me how I can change this column to DATE data type or any other alternative to get the solution of this.

I'm working with Scala and SQL on Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

what about changing `SELECT MAX(Period_Ending_Date) FROM final_table` to `SELECT MAX(cast(Period_Ending_Date as date)) FROM final_table` - performing explicit casting to date if date format is ISO8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) or using the `to_date` function ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/to_date.html)) to convert non-standard dates.

Comment: Still not changes to DATE format. I tried this code to check the datatype :                   `describe select Period_Ending_Date from final_table 
WHERE Period_Ending_Date = (SELECT MAX(cast(Period_Ending_Date as date)) FROM final_table)`